# Idea SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Any quick doc / pdf to understand basics that i can print and have idea?
Not 2k8... by quick book i meant something of this sort: http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid87_gci1052507_mem1,00.html?ShortReg=1&mboxConv=searchSQLServer_RegActivate_Submit&

Little concepts and than the commands. I got it for backup restore etc... don;t know how good it is... but better are still expected :)

Comment: Which kind of document would you like to find?  "quick doc"= do you mean short, as in reference card of sort.  "SQL 2000" do you mean specifically the server (how to configure it, install it...)  or do you imply the language (T-SQL) ... Please add precision to your question.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=A6F79CB1-A420-445F-8A4B-BD77A7DA194B&displaylang=en

This is the link to Microsoft's Books Online for SQL Server 2000.

I'm assuming you meant specifically the 2000 release and not 2005 or 2008.

You could also very likely pick up some SQL Server 2000 books very inexpensively if you can find them online or at used book stores.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a SQL Server 2008 cheat sheet [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/02/sql-server-2008-cheat-sheet-one-page-pdf-download/)... It has frequently used commands etc all boxed up into a nice PDF you can print.

If it's tutorials you're after, then try something like [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/default.asp).